# Why am i getting same values of different JSON date values?

Tags: json

I do not know the reason why am i getting same values of different JSON date values.
Here is my code for parsing date values in JSON date format:

```
package com.jsondate.parsing;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class JSONDateParsing extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String myString;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        //Date d = (new Date(1266029455L));
        //Date d = (new Date(1266312467L));
        Date d = (new Date(1266036226L));


        //String s = d.getDate() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getYear() + d.getHours() + d.getMinutes() + d.getSeconds();
       // SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd @ hh:mm aa");
        //Toast.makeText(this, d.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.e("Value:", d.toString());
        myString = d.toString();
        String []words = myString.split(" ");

        for(int i = 0;i < words.length; i++)
            Log.e("Value:", words[i]);

        myString = words[2] + "-" + words[1] + "-" + words[5] + " " + words[3];

        tv.setText(myString);
        setContentView(tv);


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that, for each of those three dates, the `myString` variable winds up with the same value?  If so, what is the value?

Comment: This is the value i am getting on all the three dates: 15-Jan-1970 15:40:36
Why am i getting the same values?

Comment: When I run a snippet of your code, I get these values for the dates: `15-Jan-1970 10:40:29`, `15-Jan-1970 10:45:12`, and `15-Jan-1970 10:40:36`

Comment: That's what i am getting as well on my emulator. We are cloning an iPhone app and need to parse JSON dates. 
What will be the JSON equivalent of 13-Feb-2010 9:43:46 AM? Because i am getting this value on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no standard way of representing a date in JSON.  It looks as though what you are receiving is an integral value representing the number of **seconds** that have elapsed since the epoch of January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.  This is somewhat different than what the `Date(long date)` constructor is expecting.  The constructor is expecting **milliseconds** since the epoch.  You need to multiply the values from the JSON by 1000 to use them correctly with `Date`.

```
long jsonDate = 1266036226L;
Date date = new Date(jsonDate * 1000);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String stringDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

---

Here are the different representations for the examples that you have given.  Do they correspond with what you are expecting?

- 1266029455 <==> 12-Feb-2010 09:50:55
- 1266312467 <==> 16-Feb-2010 04:27:47
- 1266036226 <==> 12-Feb-2010 11:43:46
- 1266072180 <==> 13-Feb-2010 09:43:46

Note that the default behavior of `SimpleDateFormat` is to use the local time zone.  In my case this is GMT-0500.  A different time zone can be specified by calling the `setTimeZone` method.

Comment: Thanks Aeth! Wonder how can we display AM or PM in the above format?

Comment: As you had in your example code, you can just add `aa` to the pattern.  For example, `"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"` will place `AM` or `PM` at the end of the string.

Comment: I see!And what about 12 hour format because this format might be 24 hours ...isn't it(i.e. 3:00 PM will be 15:00)? I want 3:00 PM to display as 3:00 PM and not 15:00 PM.Thank you

Comment: The pattern `hh` is 12-hour format.  If you would like 24-hour format, use `HH`.  See the [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more information on all of the possible patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d1 = ui.item.IssueDate;
var d = new Date(parseInt(d1.slice(6, -2)));
var Issdate = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + d.getFullYear().toString();
$('#IssueDate').val(Issdate);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)